# React, как до загрузки основного приложения показывать прелоадер?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Всегда довольно долго просто показывается белый экран, пробовал через suspense и lazy. Но так нужно относительно долго ждать загрузки самого реакта и компонента прелоадера. Пробовал создать элемент в самом dom дереве и подгружать необходимые стили через preload, но так, я не знаю почему, не получалось использовать загруженные стили, браузер их не видел. И я не знаю можно ли так вообще делать.
Просто хочу узнать как правильно делать прелоадер, чтобы он как можно раньше загрузился. Пытаюсь это сделать для low-end mobile.
Заранее большое спасибо за ответ

```
body {
    background: rgb(15, 22, 36);
    position: relative;
}
.loader {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: #000;
}
.spinner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    background-size: 100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    z-index: 1000;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
        <meta
            name="description"
            content="Web site created using create-react-app" />

        <style>
            @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Franklin:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap");
        </style>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
        <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
        <link rel="preload" href="style.css" as="style" />
        <title>React App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div class="loader"><div class="spinner">312</div></div>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: инспектор]
[image: application]

в консоли:

```
the resource http://localhost:3000/style.css was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate "as" value and it is preloaded intentionally.
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145522/discussion-on-question-by-nick-react------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приведу небольшой пример кода, о котором упоминал в комментарии, вариант вполне рабочий, при желании можно улучшить. Суть метода, добавить в `div#root` некоторую верстку которая будет автоматически замещена при загрузке реакта. Разумеется, такой метод можно рассматривть как крайний шаг когда не помогают другие оптимизации, `js` в данном случае использовать не рекомендую, воизбежание различных крэшей.

На всякий случай (для быстрого интернета) добавлю гифку как оно работает у меня:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .loader {
          width: 100vw;
          height: 100vh; 
          font-size: 40px;
        }
        .loader::after{
          content: "Loading...";
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"><div class="loader"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Load our React component. -->
    <script type="text/babel">
      const App = () => {
        return (
          <div>
            <p>Hello</p>
          </div>
        );
      };
      ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```